# Filter Documentation proposed tags to see only those we can commit for

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-proposals

In the [proposed tags tab](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation?tab=proposed) of Documentation, could it be possible to filter the propositions to get only those we can commit to?

Since there are a lot of them, it would be nice to see only those where we have at least 1 positively scored answer in, since we can't commit without this requirement.

Comment: You mean like the suggested tag synonyms system? http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest

Comment: "You mean **like** the suggested tag synonyms system?" The tag synonyms suggestion has a feature like you describe.

Comment: @Braiam Sorry, didn't catch the "like". Yes, like that. I didn't know about the feature you mentioned.